# Running an application containing white spaces in path using Python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to run an application which the user will specify in a file and it's path may or may not contain spaces.. So below is my code.

```
command1 ='\''+'"'+DIRECTORY+'"'+'\''
command = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/somepath/inside_somepath/Application_name.EXE"'
# Checking for difference
print [i for i in xrange(len(command)) if command1[i] !=command[i]]
if (command1==command):
    os.system ("start /min \"\" " + command)
    print "Equal"
else:
    print "Not Equal"

#DIRECTORY is a variable taken from a file . In that File I have written only one line & 
#that is : C:/Program Files (x86)/somepath/inside_somepath/Application_name.EXE
```

When I run `os.system ("start /min \"\" " + command)` then It opens the application, But when I run `os.system ("start /min \"\" " + command1)`. It won't

Ideally both command1 & command should be same, But when I compare I get this result

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 
57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]

Not Equal
```

Also Note that I have removed the character '\n' when I read the data from the file.So,can someone please explain me that why they seem to be different to python.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`command1` and `command` are NOT equal, `command1` is surrounded by '' (apostrophe or single quote) characters. 
Try printing `command1` and `command` to see the path strings

```
command1 = '\'' + '"'+DIRECTORY+'"' + '\''
command  = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/somepath/inside_somepath/Application_name.EXE"'

print command1
print command
```

I suspect you are trying to do this

```
command1 = '"' + DIRECTORY + '"'
command  = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/somepath/inside_somepath/Application_name.EXE"'
```

Comment: Yes I was trying to do the same! It worked. Thanks @Kagiso Mogane